# calculate distance between two points as radius of a circle then calculate area and perimeter using python class

Tags: python, class, oop

I have been playing around my code, written the formulas, but need help in reorganizing to execute python codes as expected.

1. User enters as a pair of coordinates,
2. the code calculates the distance formula which in turn is the radius of the circle,
3. then I will calculate the (a) area and (b) perimeter of the circle based on the entered coordinates of the points.

I defined my formulas in a class circle. Need help in rewriting the whole code below to work. Right now only the inputs work.

```
import math

class Circle():
    def __init__(self, r, a, p):
        self.radius = r
        self.area = a
        self.perimeter = p
    
    def point_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        r = math.sqrt(((y2-y1)**2) + ((x2-x1)**2))
        return r
    
    def area(self):
        a = 2*math.pi*self.radius**2
        return a
    
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*self.radius*3.14

    x1, y1 = input("Enter the coordinates of the center of the circle (x, y): ").split(',')
    x2, y2 = input("Enter the coordinates of the point on the circle (x, y): ").split(',')
        
    x1,y1 = int(x1), int(y1)
    x2,y2 = int(x2), int(y2)
    
   # distance = math.sqrt((y2-y1)**2) + ((x2-x1)**2)
    print(f"The radius of the circle is {point_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):.2f}")

## the code is not returning anything. Only the input works.
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
import math

class Circle():
    def point_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
        r = math.sqrt((y2-y1)**2 + (x2-x1)**2)
        return r
        
    def area_calc(r):
        a = 2*math.pi*r**2
        return a
        
    def perimeter_calc(r):
        p = 2*r*3.14
        return p


############
def main():
    x1, y1 = input("Enter the coordinates of the center of the circle (x, y): ").split(',')
    x2, y2 = input("Enter the coordinates of the point on the circle (x, y): ").split(',')
        
    x1,y1 = int(x1), int(y1)
    x2,y2 = int(x2), int(y2)

    radius = Circle.point_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    area = Circle.area_calc(radius)
    perimeter = Circle.perimeter_calc(radius)
    print("Radius :", radius)
    print("Area :", area)
    print("Perimeter :", perimeter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
Enter the coordinates of the center of the circle (x, y): 1,2
Enter the coordinates of the point on the circle (x, y): 3,4
Radius : 2.8284271247461903
Area : 50.265482457436704
Perimeter : 17.762522343406076
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear on what I am looking for. I rephrased my question above.

Comment: Hi, I have made an update, please check

Comment: Thank you @dimz , it is working now